# Magento attribute show in dropdown menu

Tags: magento, attributes, static-block

I have make different attribute in my webshop.

Now well a show only in my dropdown menu show the attribute model, brands and category.
It's possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

In short answer - Yes! It's possible.
In longer answer - stackoverflow is community who help programmers with specific code. Show some example or just google it from start point.

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/lk96nl6) is amazing resources who can help you.